# Cannot using (id) that selected from (select option) and put it into my list object to find price?

Tags: laravel

i am work on laravel framework i want to get price by selected option , in the script i get (id) but i cannot use this (id) in to my object to get the price.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('select[name="surgSelect"]').on('change', function() {
            var id=document.getElementById("surgSelect").value;
            var price={{$list->where('sdf_id',id)->pluck('price')->first()}}
            document.getElementById("price").value = price;
          });
      });
   </script>
```

Error Exception

```
"Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing.

Comment: This is not possible, `{{$list->where('sdf_id',id)->pluck('price')->first()}}` is outputted on page compilation way before `document.getElementById("surgSelect").value;`̀is executed

Comment: when i use value rather than (id) it is working !      {{$list->where('sdf_id','207')->pluck('price')->first()}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible because the PHP code is outputted to the HTML on the server side way before the `id` from your javascript becomes available so what you need to do is to send an Ajax request to get the price like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="surgSelect"]').on('change', function() {
        var id = document.getElementById("surgSelect").value;
        $.post('/getPrice', {id: id})
            .done(function(response) {
                document.getElementById("price").value = response;
        });
    });
});
```

And in the Backend (for example `routes\web.php`)

```php
Route::post('getPrice', function() {
    return $list->where('sdf_id', request('id'))->pluck('price')->first();
});
```